# How to restore all PostgreSQL databases from a .sql script

Tags: postgresql

I accidentally ran a python script that imported a lot of data in to the database. I have a backup `.sql` that is a `PostgreSQL database cluster dump` that I would like to use to do a full restore. The problem i have is that this `.sql` has everything in it, including the creation of all databases and the roles like `postgres`, etc.

I can't just use a command like `psql -U username -d myDataBase -a -f backup.sql` to overwrite everything because all these users, tables and databases already exist.

I would like to know what is the proper way to do this. Do you have to drop everything and then run the `.sql` script. If so what command can you use to drop everything and how do you run a `psql` command with no users if you drop everything. I have root access if that helps. The version of PostgreSQL is 15.

Comment: 1) To be clear by `cluster dump` you mean the output of `pg_dumpall` correct? 2) If so probably the best way to do this is create a new Postgres cluster then a) Restore the `pg_dumpall` output to it. b) Do `pg_dump  -Fc -d <the_database_you_need> ...` from the new instance. 3) Use that output as input to `pg_restore` as something like `pg_restore -d postgres -c -C -U <some_user> dump_file` to the existing cluster. **NOTE**, the `-c -C`  combination will DROP the database in the existing cluster before rebuilding it from the dump file.

Comment: 1) I actually don't know. That is what's written inside the generated file that I was given. I hoped people here would be able to recognize if it's from that. 2) Thank you i will give it a go.

Comment: 1) So yes it is plain text output from `pg_dumpall`. 2) To be clear this involves doing an `initdb` to create an entirely new Postgres cluster of the same version you are currently running.